# How to disable some menu items according to the users selected in the form for selecting users

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

Am doing a project in C#.net.I have to use the same forms to all kind of users but by controlling their access by disabling some menu items to some users.For example i have 2 main users(Admin and Employee).Admin have all the controls over the forms but employees are having some restrictions.This restriction is applied in the form by disabling some menu items. Is there any way to code this.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is way too broad for SO. You need to take an approach and then ask specific questions about the approach. Not ask "how do I program this?"

Comment: and ... If its asp.net project and you don't know where to begin. This will give you some ideas http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+menu+control+role+based&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a kind of Acl system such as in PHP. 
When your user is log just check if he have the right to acces in the menu. but be carefull when the menu isn't show that doesn't mean it is disable.

Comment: Thanks David for valuable suggestion.